# ant design - Modal value reset on "cancel" and "X" close button - API RESPONSE BASE REACT JS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, antd

Using `.map`, I mapped all cards and each card has an edit button, so when I click the edit button it opens a Modal (antd) that has a form with input values. Values are bound with API, and when I open any card model it shows perfect values in input.

Problem is, when I click any other card's edit button, it shows again the same values (previous popup values)

code:

```
{surveys.length > 0 && surveys.map((survey, i) => (
  <Col className="gutter-row" xs={24} sm={12} md={12} lg={6} xl={6} key={survey.publicID}>
    <Card
      cover={<Link to='/survey'><img alt="example" src={ survey.imagePath || "https://gw.alipayobjects.com/zos/rmsportal/JiqGstEfoWAOHiTxclqi.png"} /></Link>}
      actions={[
        <img className="icons-svgs" src="/svg/Share.svg" onClick={() => this.onHandleShareSurvey(survey)} />, 
        <img className="icons-svgs" src="/svg/Edit.svg" onClick={() => this.onHandleEditSurvey(survey)} />, 
        <img className="icons-svgs" src="/svg/Duplicate.svg" onClick={()=>this.onHandleDuplicateSurvey(survey)} />, 
        <img className="icons-svgs" src="/svg/Delete.svg" onClick={() => this.onHandleDeleteSurvey(survey)}/>
      ]} >
      <Row type="flex" align="middle">
        <Col span={18}>
        <Link to='/survey'>
          <Meta
            title={survey.Name}
            description={survey.Description}
          />
        </Link>
        </Col>
        <Col type="flex" span={6} align="middle">
          <span onClick={()=> this.setUploadDataSurvey(true)}>
            <Icon type="upload" className="upload-icon"/>
          </span>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Card>
  </Col>
))}
```

And popup component is:

```
<Modal
    visible={visible}
    onCancel={onCancel}
    // onOk={() => this.setEditSurvey(false)}
    title="Edit survey"
    className= "surveys-popup"
    style={{ top: 20 }}
    destroyOnClose={true}
    footer={false}
>
    <Form onSubmit={this.handleEdit}>
    <p className="form-title">What is your product?</p>

    <FormItem key={10}>
    {getFieldDecorator('Name', {
      rules: [{ required: false, message: 'Title Can\'t leave blank' }],
    })(
      <div className="form-input">
        <Input ref="Name" defaultValue={survey.Name}/>
      </div>
    )}
    </FormItem>
     <p className="form-title">Please describe your product</p>
    <div className="form-input">
    <FormItem key={11}>
    {getFieldDecorator('Description', {
      rules: [{ required: false, message: 'Description Can\'t leave blank' }],
    })(
      <div className="form-input">
        <TextArea autosize={{ minRows: 2, maxRows: 6 }} ref="Description" defaultValue={survey.Description}/>        
      </div>
    )}
    </FormItem>
    </div>

    <div span={24} className="upload-images-container">
      <div className="clearfix">
        <Upload
        action="//jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/"
        listType="picture-card"
        fileList={fileList}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        >
        {fileList.length >= 3 ? null : uploadButton}
        </Upload>
      </div>


    </div>
    <p className="form-title">Define your probability model <Icon type="info-circle" className="small-icon" /></p>
    <div className="model-table">
      <div className="table-column">
        <div span={24} className="model-table-title">Too cheap %</div>
        <div span={24} className="model-table-value">
        <FormItem key={12}>
          {getFieldDecorator('tooCheap', {
            rules: [{ required: false, message: '' }],
          })(
            <div className="form-input">
              <Input type="number" defaultValue={survey.tooCheap}/>        
            </div>
          )}
          </FormItem>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="table-column">
        <div span={24} className="model-table-title">Very cheap %</div>
        <div span={24} className="model-table-value">
        <FormItem key={13}>
          {getFieldDecorator('veryCheap', {
            rules: [{ required: false, message: '' }],
          })(
            <div className="form-input">
              <Input type="number" defaultValue={survey.veryCheap}/>        
            </div>
          )}
          </FormItem>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="table-column">
        <div span={24} className="model-table-title">Cheap %</div>
        <div span={24} className="model-table-value">
          <FormItem key={14}>
          {getFieldDecorator('cheap', {
            rules: [{ required: false, message: '' }],
          })(
            <div className="form-input">
              <Input type="number" defaultValue={survey.cheap}/>        
            </div>
          )}
          </FormItem>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="table-column">
        <div span={24} className="model-table-title">Correct price %</div>
        <div span={24} className="model-table-value">
          <FormItem key={15}>
          {getFieldDecorator('correctPrice', {
            rules: [{ required: false, message: '' }],
          })(
            <div className="form-input">
              <Input type="number" defaultValue={survey.correctPrice}/>        
            </div>
          )}
          </FormItem>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="table-column">
        <div span={24} className="model-table-title">Expensive %</div>
        <div span={24} className="model-table-value">
          <FormItem key={16}>
          {getFieldDecorator('expensive', {
            rules: [{ required: false, message: '' }],
          })(
            <div className="form-input">
              <Input type="number" defaultValue={survey.expensive}/>        
            </div>
          )}
          </FormItem>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <Row>
    <Col xs={24} sm={12} md={12} lg={12} xl={12}>
      <div className="form-title"><p>Choose a password <Icon type="info-circle" className="small-icon" /> (optional)</p>
      <div>
        <FormItem key={17}>
        {getFieldDecorator('password', {
          rules: [{ required: false, message: '' }],
        })(
          <div className="form-input">
            <Input />        
          </div>
        )}
        </FormItem>
        <FormItem key={17} className="hidden">
        {getFieldDecorator('publicID', {
          rules: [{ required: false, message: '' }],
        })(
          <div className="form-input">
            <Input value={survey.publicID}/>        
          </div>
        )}
        </FormItem>
        {/* <input value={survey.publicID} ref="publicID"/> */}
      </div>
      </div>
    </Col>
    <Col xs={24} sm={12} md={8} lg={8} xl={8} offset={4}>
      <div className="form-title">
      <p>(optional)</p>
      <div>
        <Upload key={10}>
        <Button><Icon type="upload" /> UPLOAD DATA</Button>
        </Upload>

      </div>
      </div>
    </Col>
    </Row>
    <Row className="footer-cta">
      <Button key="back" onClick={onCancel}>Cancel</Button>
      <Button key="submit" type="primary" visible={visible} htmlType="submit" onClick={onCancel}>
        Save
      </Button>
    </Row>
  </Form>
</Modal>
```

Comment: Are you still facing an issue with your code?

Comment: set ***destroyOnClose={true}*** for modal props. I hope this would help. Please provide a CodeSandbox or Codepen for more help.

Answer (score 34):

I had a similar issue, whereby I needed the content of the `Modal` to re-render when re-opening - i.e. a modal showing content based on a button being clicked, but after closing the modal, it would show the same data when re-opened.

Adding `destroyOnClose={true}` to my `Modal` properties solved this issue for me. Now, closing a Modal would destroy it, and each time the modal is opened, it would re-fetch dynamic content based on the button used to open it.

i.e.

```
<Modal
    destroyOnClose={true}
    visible={this.state.modalVisible}
    title="Example Modal"
    onOk={this.changeTimeModalHandleOk}
    onCancel={this.changeTimeModalHandleCancel}
>
    ...Dynamic Modal Content Here...
</Modal>
```

Comment: Thank you, I have been trying to figure this out for hours. You are my hero.

Answer (score 9):

I got problem when trying to initialize value for a form by setState. the form didn't get value from the State. Found out this solution

```
<Modal destroyOnClose>
  <Form preserve={false} >
</Modal>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. 
Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please edit your question and explain 
how it answers the specific question being asked.

Comment: I lost two days with the modal keeping the values. This saved me!

Answer (score 3):

I am using antd 4.2 and I had been facing the same issue, when I clicked on update button to show the edit form in a model but the model was showing same same values for different records, `destroyOnClose={true}` fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to re-create the Modal whenever it becomes visible. This way it will not cache any previous form values, and will be initialized with whatever the initial field values given.

`{isVisible && <Modal visible/>`

Comment: Note that this will lose the close animation on `<Modal />`

Answer (score 0):

Try conditionally render Modal component. It will be mount and unmount Modal depending on state of isModalVisible.

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
  const [isModalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);
  
  return (
    <>
      {isModalVisible ? <Modal /> : null}
    </>
  )
```